# How to retrieve Listview.Item from inner control?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, uwp

So I have this relatively simple problem: I have the following ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid">
                <HyperlinkButton Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And I want to delete that particular item when the HyperlinkButton_Click event is fired. I've tried various things such as this:

```
PinOutDetails p = ((sender as HyperlinkButton).Parent as Grid).Parent as PinOutDetails;
lstView.Items.Remove(p);
```

But obviously, it doesn't work... So how can I get the Listview.Item (the PinOutDetails class) from inside one of it's child controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You last .Parent should be .DataContext as the DataContext of the Parent Grid should be your class you passed through.

```
PinOutDetails p = ((sender as HyperlinkButton).Parent as Grid).DataContext as PinOutDetails;
lstView.Items.Remove(p);
```

Unfortunately without more information such as how you are populating the list view in the first place, I can't provide more specific answers.